# Issue while Accessing a Global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am unable to access NatArray[ ] in the second function, and u4count in the second function is coming as 0. What may be the reason?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var NatArray = [];
var NatArrayloc = [];
var u4count = 0;

function Check1()
{
NatArray[0] = 202116108;
NatArrayloc[0] = 202116109;
NatArray[1] = 202116111;
NatArrayloc[1] = 202116112;
NatArray[2] = 202116113;
NatArrayloc[2] = 202116114;
u4count = 3;
}
function Check()
{
 alert("coming here" + u4count + "natentry" + NatArray[0] );
}
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's with the `<!--` at the start of the script? This should prevent parsing of the script at all.

Comment: Moreover **when/how you call** Check1() and Check()?

Comment: Here should be end of the comments for old browser without scripting

Comment: @Sirko In fact no. It's just garbage.

Comment: Got your code on fiddle. Did you call any of the functions ?
http://jsfiddle.net/URX5A/

Answer (score 1):

Works for me as excpected. **The order** you call your functions **is important** in this case:

```
var NatArray = [];
var NatArrayloc = [];
var u4count = 0;

function Check1() {
    NatArray[0] = 202116108;
    NatArrayloc[0] = 202116109;
    NatArray[1] = 202116111;
    NatArrayloc[1] = 202116112;
    NatArray[2] = 202116113;
    NatArrayloc[2] = 202116114;
    u4count = 3;
}

function Check() {
    alert("coming here " + u4count + " natentry " + NatArray[0]);
}

Check1();
Check();
```

As some answering users figured out is the unclosed inline comment bad but not the reason for your problem. [Something about comments in inline-code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents#Use_of_Comments_Inside_Inline_style_and_script)

http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8sKf/

Comment: @AJ. The difference is, that I don't prise to remove the unclosed inline-comment.

Comment: 1. Umm, you have removed them yourself
2. The unclosed comment DOES cause problems. Please see the two jsfiddle examples from the other comment

Comment: @AJ. You can re-add it and it will work as excpected too ;) http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8sKf/1/

Comment: @Aj  ...and by the way, I don't voted your answer down, I just gave you a reason why your answer is bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can call this 2 functions in `window.onload` so it will call second function and also alert and `NatArray[ ]` value inside alert.

Try something like this:

```
var NatArray = [];
var NatArrayloc = [];
var u4count = 0;

function Check1() {
    NatArray[0] = 202116108;
    NatArrayloc[0] = 202116109;
    NatArray[1] = 202116111;
    NatArrayloc[1] = 202116112;
    NatArray[2] = 202116113;
    NatArrayloc[2] = 202116114;
    u4count = 3;
}

function Check() {
    alert("coming here " + u4count + " natentry " + NatArray[0]);
}

 window.onload=function(){
        Check1();
        Check();
    };
```

Comment: @yckart ,he said unable to access NatArray[ ] in the second function so i call this 2 function in window.onload so it will call second function and also alert and NatArray[ ] value inside alert.

Comment: Don't tell that to me... the questioner is unsuspecting ;)

Comment: ...and by the way, this is not his problem ;) The order is the important part here!

Comment: yes the order was the problem , i put here a prototype code its calling in several places ,one place the order was not proper .
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/R23eD/

<strike>You need to remove the `<!--` from your script start. And you're also not calling the `Check1()` function to initialize the values</strike>

Comment: That's wrong! The unclosed comment will ignored by any browser!

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gPjfR/ - Here the JS does not work as opposed to http://jsfiddle.net/R23eD/